# 3d plot with given 2d data

Tags: matlab

I want to understand how the 2d data is related to z axis to get the 3d plots

let us say that i have `x=[-1:0.1:1]`, vector

and `y=[1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0]`

a plot of y Vs x will have peak of 5 and slope down to both sides at x=0.5
how to relate these data in 3d to get the bell shape surface, with similar characteristics.

Comment: you can't plot your `x` vs `y`. they are of different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

You can view a line/curve plot as a function of a single variable, `y=f(x)`, and typically, `x` and `y` are both vectors. For e.g., you can plot the Gaussian bell curve as

```
x=linspace(-3,3,1000);
y=exp(-x.^2/2);
plot(x,y)
```

A surface plot, on the other hand, is a function of two variables, `z=f(x,y)` where `x` and `y` can be either vectors or matrices and `z` is a matrix. [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) is a very handy function that generates 2D `x` and `y` arrays from 1D vectors by proper replication.

It is the `z` matrix that you plot either as a 2D image (values of `z` are represented by colors) or a 3D plot (values of `z` are represented as heights along the z-axis). For e.g., a 3D Gaussian bell curve can be plotted as

```
x=linspace(-3,3,1000);y=x';               %'
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z=exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/2);
surf(x,y,z);shading interp
```

This is how the respective plots should look like

[image]