# (Matlab) How can I make 3D plot from 2D experimatal data?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

There are 2D experimental data.

```
z=load('data.txt');
x=z(:,1);
y=z(:,2);
plot(x,y)][1]
```

I want to make it to 3D as the link did.

Here is a link. [3d plot with given 2d data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909998/3d-plot-with-given-2d-data)

Comment: You should do the same as in the ohter example. However, x and you must be defined as matrices (eg, with meshgrid) and z must as a matrix with the same dimension.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you want to plot. Your input data z contains x and y values ( `z=[x;y]` ), right? And what shall be plotted on your third dimension?

Answer (score 0):

The question and answer is a bit misleading, since the question is actually not regarding data but the bell function (or triangular function). They are symmetric and have corresponding 2D versions (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function).

```
y=exp(-x.^2/2); %1D
z=exp(-(X.^2+Y.^2)/2); %2D
```

In general, however, this is not the case. Your data, for instance, is not 2D:

```
z=load('data.txt');
x=z(:,1);
y=z(:,2);
```

x is 1D and y is your dependent variable. If x and y were independent you would have a third variable (e.g. z):

```
x=[0,1,2];
y=[0,1,2];
z=[1,2,3;
   2,2,2;
   3,2,1];
```

The entries in z would then be z(x,y) (e.g. z(3,3)=1).

To sum up the confusion:

When you plot a 1D function it is plotted in 2D (x,y),
and when you plot a 2D function it is plotted in 3D (x,y,z), (x,y,colors) or (x,y,z and colors) (the latter is what is used in the mentioned question).